# Shader not working on ThreeJS Upgrade - 'viewMartrix: redefinition

Tags: graphics, three.js, glsl

Seems as you upgrade Three.js it complains about a redfinition of both  `viewMatrix` and `camera`

```
  #define MAX_DIR_LIGHTS 0
  #define MAX_POINT_LIGHTS 0
  #define MAX_SPOT_LIGHTS 0
  #define MAX_HEMI_LIGHTS 0
  #define MAX_SHADOWS 0

  uniform mat4 viewMatrix;
  uniform vec3 cameraPosition;
  uniform vec3 diffuse;
  uniform float opacity;
```

Am wondering why this is happening and how to resolve it?

Have [made a codepen](https://codepen.io/redrubia/pen/ZEezjVw) to show the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This occurs because when using `ShaderMaterial`, the renderer appends several standard definitions to the shader. Here are the first 8 lines:

```glsl
precision highp float;
precision highp int;
#define HIGH_PRECISION
#define SHADER_NAME ShaderMaterial
#define GAMMA_FACTOR 2
uniform mat4 viewMatrix;
uniform vec3 cameraPosition;
uniform bool isOrthographic;
```

Then when you add your own uniforms, you're attempting to redefine them:

```glsl
uniform mat4 viewMatrix;
uniform vec3 cameraPosition;
uniform vec3 diffuse;
uniform float opacity;
```

This is what's causing the error.

You can either get rid of the `uniforms` that are duplicated, to avoid the redefinitions, or you could [use a `RawShaderMaterial`](https://threejs.org/docs/?q=rawshader#api/en/materials/RawShaderMaterial) instead. However, keep in mind that it works just like ShaderMaterial, except that definitions of built-in uniforms and attributes are not automatically prepended to the GLSL shader code. So you might have to add them yourself.

Comment: Thank you! I removed this and seems it continues on to work!